# Many to Many Relationship

Tags: ssas

I have the following scenario:
Fact table A linked to Dimensions D1, D2, D3, D4, D5
Fact table B linked to Dimensions D1, D2, D3

I want that D4 is linked to Fact B. I can use Fact A for this. Fact A will be used as a Many-to-Many Relationship.

Is such an approach of using an existing fact as a M2M relationship good practice?
Also, in SSAS you do not specify which dimensions will be linked (when using M2M). Does this mean that I would have to link both D4 and D5? and what happens to D1,D2,D3? Are they linked again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally fine to have a many-to-many relationship table containing facts. In fact, for currency conversions, this is a standard case, where the exchange rate is the fact in the table relating time and possibly transaction currency to the target currency.

And you do configure the many-to-many relationship for every dimension: On the "Dimension Usage" tab of Cube Designer, you configure e. g. at the row for dimension D4 and the column for measure group B that this relationship is via the many-to-many table A. If you configure the cell in the same column for the D5 dimension as "No Relationship" (i. e. gray), this dimension will not be related to the measures of measure group B.